# How do I send multiple images to tumblr via their API with Node?

Tags: node.js, tumblr

Tumblr's [documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#pphoto-posts) says that you can send an array or "(URL-encoded binary contents)" in order to post a photo message.

What does "URL-encoded binary contents" actually mean and how do I accomplish this with Node?

I have this function that I've been using to get files from a URL:

```
function getImage (url) {
  return new RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Request.get({
      url: url,
      encoding: null,
    }, (err, response, body) => {
      if (!err && response && response.statusCode == 200 && body) {
        const buff = Buffer.from(body);
        return resolve(buff.toString()); 
        // I've tried all kinds of stuff here:
        // return resolve(buff.toString('hex')); //nope
        // return resolve(buff.toString('binary')); //nope
        // return resolve(buff.toString('base64')); //nope
        // return resolve(encodeURIComponent(buff.toString('hex')); //nope
        // etc.

      }
    });
  });
};
```

I then use the result of that function to populate the `data` parameter of the POST request.  I am able to use my POST function to send regular text posts, and image posts if I specify the `source` (url) of the image rather than the data itself. So I don't think it's an OAuth problem.

The error message I get is:

```
{
  'meta': {
    'status': 400,
    'msg': 'Bad Request',
  },
  'response': { 'errors': ['Nice image, but we don\'t support that format. Try resaving it as a gif, jpg, or png.'] },
};
```

I am sending it JPEGs and GIFs, just not in the way they want it. How do I go from the result of a GET to whatever it is that tumblr wants?

Comment: In the years since I asked this question, tumblr has released an updated post creation API that can be found here: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts---createreblog-a-post-neue-post-format

It appears to explain in detail how to submit multiple images (and other media) for the purposes of creating a post.  I no longer care about this question, so I haven't actually tried it out.  But if you DO care, hopefully it will help you.